# Sed splitting up every input line

Tags: unix, sed

Is there a way using sed, to make the first two words of every input line appear on one line, and the remainder of input line on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sed solution:

```
echo "one two three filer"|sed -e "s/\([^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}[^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\(.*\)$/\1\n\2/g"
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know with `sed` but here is an `awk`

```
cat file
This is a test for me
Lets see how this goes
```

```
awk '{print $1,$2;for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
This is
a test for me
Lets see
how this goes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}\)\{2\}/&\
/' YourFile
```

assuming separator of word are space character (if not, replace the  space char by `[[:blank:]]` or `[[:space:]]`)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s\+/\n/2' file
```